# How to kill bash script with CTRL+C

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which runs a function 10 times, and this function runs 20 imagemagick commands. Every time I press ctrl+C it moves onto the next imagemagick command so it takes 200 ctrl+c's to close the file.

How do I stop it with ctrl+c properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Ctrl+Z` (suspend) and then check output of `jobs` command. Your script / job should be listed as "Stopped". Then you could simply run `kill %i` where `i` is the number inside the `[]` in `jobs` output.

Alternatively you could issue a `pkill -9 -f <your_script_name>` from another session

Answer (score 0):

check this answer "How to kill a script running in terminal, without closing terminal (Ctrl + C doesn't work)?": `https://askubuntu.com/questions/520107/how-to-kill-a-script-running-in-terminal-without-closing-terminal-ctrl-c-doe`